# Is @NamedQuery necessary when mapping entity to a view?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

From many examples online, I saw people add @NamedQuery before their entity class, I removed the annotation and it still works, so I am curious if it's necessary to always add this annotation to entities? BTW, I am using Spring data as the JPA vendor.

What's the best practice here and why?

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmailAddress",
  query = "select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
public class User {
  //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, named queries are not needed.  They allow you to predefine queries and then use them at runtime rather than dynamically creating each query.  This is described in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)